# How can I deal with this warning: hash mismatch?

Tags: ios, xcode7.3

After I update `Xcode 7.3` and run the project,I get a warning :

> hash mismatch: this object file was built against a different version
>   of the module
>   /Users/lu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1Q58A4KYC5CO8/SystemConfiguration-1VJ1XGF5LU890.pcm.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: This occurs for me after I run my app on a different device.  So, if I ran it on my iPhone, then re-run the app on the simulator, or vice versa.  Not sure why it's happening, but I can reproduce it when I switch devices.

Answer (score 29):

I have just had a similar error and you can solve it by cleaning and building again.

Regards and happy coding.

Comment: Cleaning the project does indeed work, but why, what's they underlying cause?

Comment: I have no idea, I just made a small change in a file and then the error appear, and I just change a variable name nothing important, so is a mystery to me, in fact this is the only question about the theme that I found over the Web

Comment: For the record, to get this to go away I also had to clean the build folder (CMD + OPT + SHIFT + K)

Comment: Cleaning does not help me at this point, and this across multiple build machines. I'm wondering if I need to rebuild some libraries...

Comment: I delete a path in the target Framework search paths then the warming is disappeared.

Comment: Cleaning the project does remove the warning but i get it again after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to clean **Derived Data**!

1. Close Xcode
2. Finder > Go > Go to Folder...
3. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
4. Select All
5. Move to Trash
6. Re-open Xcode